# Chrome messaging: "receiving end does not exist" and "port closed before a response was received"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Everything seems to work alright, but these errors keep getting thrown:

1) "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."

2) "Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received."

It started happening when I started messaging my content script from my background script. Here's what I added to background.js:

```
  chrome.windows.getAll({populate:true},
    function(windows)
    {
      windows.forEach(function(window)
      {
        window.tabs.forEach(function(tab)
        {
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {msg: "FINITO!"}, function(){
            console.log("?");
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

contentscript.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(response, sender, sendResponse)
  {
    alert("i gotchu");

    //copypasted this from stackoverflow as a fix, I don't really know what this is for and it doesn't seem to work loll
    return Promise.resolve("Dummy response to keep the console quiet");
  });
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Drill Sergeant",
  "description": "Tracks time spent on 'watchlist' websites",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "browser_action": {"default_popup": "popup.html"},
  "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
  "content_scripts": [{"matches": ["<all_urls>"], "js": ["contentscript.js"]}],
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "webNavigation", "notifications", "tabs", "background"]
}
```

What do errors 1) and 2) mean? How would you fix them? I get the "i gotchu" alert every time that code executes, so it seems like the messaging is working, but I have no idea why those errors always show up with the alerts...

EDIT: I did more testing and the alerts only showed on the active tab, so I guess the messaging doesn't really work.

Comment: Chrome API doesn't support Promise so it's just ignored. Instead you should use `sendResponse('whatever')` also make sure to read the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) so that you know what you're doing. For example, if you don't need a response then remove the callback from sendMessage and don't use sendResponse.

Comment: As for `alert` it's probably the worst method of debugging. Chrome doesn't even show it in inactive tabs. Use `console.log` or debug directly in devtools using breakpoints.